# Remove an object from an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, overloading

I have an array of pointers that point to `Building` objects that look like this:

```cpp
class Building {
    int id ;
    int year;
    double price;
    char* adress;
};
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove objects from the array via the `id` using `operator-`, but I don't really know how to do so. My list class looks like this:

```cpp
class List {
    Building* buildingList[10];
    static int buildingNr;
    
public:
    
    List operator-(int id) {
        bool exists = false;
        int index;
    
        for(int i = 0; i < buildingNr; i++)
            if (buildingList[i]->getId() == id) {
                exists = true;
                index = i;
                cout << "Building " << index << " was deleted." << endl;
            }
    
        if (exists) {
            delete buildingList[index];
            buildingList[index] = buildingList[buildingNr];
            buildingList[buildingNr] = NULL;
            buildingNr--;
        }
        else throw - 1;
    } 
};
    
int List::buildingNr = 0;
```

I know that there are far easier ways of doing this, like using `std::vector`, but this is an assignment and I have to do it using the overloaded `operator-` and an array of pointers, and the `Building` class has to look like that.

I also have the `operator+` which adds an element to the array, and that works fine.

Comment: Not 100% clear ion what you're asking, but assuming `buildingNr` is the number of items in the list, `buildingList[buildingNr]` is going to be out of range. You could `buildingNr--` first or `buildingList[buildingNr-1]`.

Comment: Some handy reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) The wisdom contained therein will help you get the basic shape of your operator right.

Comment: Replace the `char *` with `std::string`.  Character arrays are a pain, especially when you have to dynamically allocate them for a structure.

Comment: One question to ask yourself before overloading an operator is "Does this behaviour make sense?" I doubt you have much say in this matter since this is homework, but always something to consider. Does making an operator `-` that performs a find-and-remove make the source code easier to read?

Comment: First I made a method for removing items, but the teacher explicitly said we have to overload the - operator to remove objects from the list. The problem is that I don't know how to remove an object from an array of pointers, since it is dinamicaly allocated. Should I use delete/delete[] or none of them and just set the pointer to NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator-` is not implemented correctly.  Although its loop to find an object is fine, removing that object is broken.  You are not updating the array correctly, as you need to shift down *ALL* of the array elements after the found index, which you are not doing.

Also, make sure your `List` class implements the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) correctly.  The return value of `operator-` is supposed to return a *new* `List` object, so a *copy* has to be made.  You should not be modifying the `this` object at all in `operator-` (that is the job of `operator-=` to do; see [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/)).

Also, the `buildingNr` member should not be `static`.  That prevents you from using multiple `List` objects at a time.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

class List {
    Building* buildingList[10];
    int buildingNr;
    
public:
    
    List() : buildingNr(0) {}

    List(const List &src) : buildingNr(src.buildingNr) {
        for(int i = 0; i < buildingNr; ++i) {
            buildingList[i] = new Building;
            buildingList[i]->id = src.buildingList[i]->id;
            buildingList[i]->year = src.buildingList[i]->year;
            buildingList[i]->price = src.buildingList[i]->price;
            buildingList[i]->adress = new char[strlen(src.buildingList[i]->adress)+1);
            strcpy(buildingList[i]->adress, src.buildingList[i]->adress);
        }
    }

    ~List() {
        for(int i = 0; i < buildingNr; ++i) {
            delete[] buildingList[i]->adress;
            delete buildingList[i];
        }
    }

    List& operator=(const List &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            List tmp(rhs);
            std::swap_ranges(buildingList, buildingList+10, tmp.buildingList);
            std::swap(buildingNr, tmp.buildingNr);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    List& operator-=(int id) {    
        for(int i = 0; i < buildingNr; ++i) {
            if (buildingList[i]->getId() == id) {
                delete buildingList[i];
                for(int j = i + 1; j < buildingNr; ++j) {
                    buildingList[j - 1] = buildingList[j];
                }
                buildingList[buildingNr] = NULL;
                --buildingNr;
                cout << "Building " << i << " was deleted." << endl;
                return *this;
            }
        }
        throw -1;
    } 

    ...
};

friend List operator-(List lhs, int id) {    
    lhs -= id;
    return lhs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the throw -1 was there so I i could treat an exception in case the id given was inexistent.